# browserify --standalone appears to work, but the exposed object is empty

Tags: javascript, browserify

I must be missing something basic.

I have a handful of node modules that use module.exports as expected. I require all of them in requireAll.js as follows:

```
const
    core          = require("./bjb-core"),
    config        = require("./bjb-config.js"),
    log           = require("./bjb-log.js"),
    digestMessage = require("./bjb-digestMessage.js"),
    password      = require("./bjb-password.js"),
    draggable     = require("./bjb-draggable.js"),
    fade          = require("./bjb-fade.js"),
    userDialog    = require("./bjb-userDialog.js"),
    post          = require("./bjb-post.js"),
    shutdown      = require("./bjb-shutdown.js");
```

I run browserify as follows:
`browserify -o bundle.js -s bjb requireAll.js`

`index.html` includes `<script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/bundle.js"></script>` in the `<head>` section.

Everything appears to have worked fine, and in the browser, the window.bjb object has been created, BUT, it has no members. It's just `window.bjb = {}`.

As an example, here is one of the simplest of the above modules:

```
digestMessage = async function digestMessage(message) {
    const msgUint8 = new TextEncoder().encode(message); // encode as (utf-8) Uint8Array
    const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", msgUint8); // hash the message
    const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer)); // convert buffer to byte array
    const hashHex = hashArray.map((b) => b.toString(16).padStart(2, "0")).join(""); // convert bytes to hex string
    return hashHex;
};

module.exports = {
    digestMessage : digestMessage
};
```

So, for example, one of the things I expect to see is `bjb.digestMessage`, but no. What am I doing wrong?